# Celery, Resque, or custom solution for processing jobs on machines in my cloud?

Tags: amazon-ec2, delayed-job, celery, resque, task-queue

My company has thousands of server instances running application code - some instances run databases, others are serving web apps, still others run APIs or Hadoop jobs.  All servers run Linux.

In this cloud, developers typically want to do one of two things to an instance:

1. Upgrade the version of the application running on that instance.  Typically this involves a) tagging the code in the relevant subversion repository, b) building an RPM from that tag, and c) installing that RPM on the relevant application server.  Note that this operation would touch four instances: the SVN server, the build host (where the build occurs), the YUM host (where the RPM is stored), and the instance running the application.

   Today, a rollout of a new application version might be to 500 instances.
2. Run an arbitrary script on the instance.   ***The script can be written in any language provided the interpreter exists on that instance***.  E.g. The UI developer wants to run his "check_memory.php" script which does x, y, z on the 10 UI instances and then restarts the webserver if some conditions are met.

What tools should I look at to help build this system?  I've seen Celery and Resque and delayed_job, but they seem like they're built for moving through a lot of tasks.  This system is under much less load - maybe on a big day a thousand hundred upgrade jobs might run, and a couple hundred executions of arbitrary scripts.  Also, they don't support tasks written in any language.

How should the central "job processor" communicate with the instances?  SSH, message queues (which one), something else?

Thank you for your help.

NOTE: this cloud is proprietary, so EC2 tools are not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

1. Set up password-less SSH on the servers, have a file that contains the list of all machines in the cluster, and run your scripts directly using SSH. For example: ssh user@foo.com "ls -la". This is the same approach used by Hadoop's cluster startup and shutdown scripts. If you want to assign tasks dynamically, you can pick nodes at random.
2. Use something like Torque or Sun Grid Engine to manage your cluster.

The package installation can be wrapped inside a script, so you just need to solve the second problem, and use that solution to solve the first one :)